# Making / Testing a Connection Using VersionOne .Net SDK

Tags: c#, .net, sdk, versionone

I'm new to VersionOne and have limited C#. Need help connecting and testing connection to VersionOne instance using .Net SDK to make sure I'm actually making a connection.

I have some sample code that runs without error, but not sure it is connecting.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using VersionOne.SDK.APIClient;

namespace VersionOneExtract3
{
    public class Connection1
    {
         V1Connector connector = V1Connector

    .WithInstanceUrl("https://www14.v1host.com/MyCompanySite")

    .WithUserAgentHeader("VersionOneExtract2", "1.0")

    .WithWindowsIntegrated("XA\\MyUsername", "MyPassword")

    .Build();
    }
}
enter code here
```

No results or errors. Is there a way I can create a variable and have it return some sort of confirmed connection info? Help appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

The code that you posted creates a VersionOne connector which is used to connect to the VersionOne API.  I'm assuming that you replaced the username and password with random data for privacy reasons, along with the URL. Make sure that those details are correct.

After you have your connector setup you'll want to use it to query various resources from the api.  One example of such is below:

```
IServices services = new Services(connector);
Oid memberId = services.GetOid("Member:20");
Query query = new Query(memberId);
QueryResult result = services.Retrieve(query);
Asset member = result.Assets[0];
```

The reason that you're not seeing any feedback from the code you posted it because in reality, it doesn't really do much other than take in some configuration data and then spit out a type of API client.

Be sure to have a good look at the documentation as they do a fairly decent job of explaining how to work with their SDK.

https://community.versionone.com/VersionOne_Connect/Developer_Library/Get_an_SDK/.NET_SDK

Answer (score 0):

Think of your code as code that describes and sets up a VersionOne connection.  You are building an object that contains everything needed for a connection.  You are not connecting yet.

if your variable **connector** is null, you know for a fact that you are not connected to VersionOne. On the other hand, your connector might have what looks like valid info in the setting up of the connection so you need to add the next piece of code

```
IServices services = new Services(connector);
```

Once you hit this piece of code, this will throw an exception if the connector object is invalid.  To get confirmation of this, connect to https://www14.v1host.com/MyCompanySiteWrongURL. If you run your code, connector will reference an object but it will have virtual "junk" in it because it won't connect.  As soon as you hit the above new code that I have suggested, it will throw an exception. Conversely, if you enter the correct URL and credentials, you should not throw an exception. You can use @DCCoders chunk of code for querying for member:20.  I also recommend using the VersionOne API to do queries in the browser so you can get instant results and get a feel of the VersionOne data model.  https://community.versionone.com/VersionOne_Connect/Developer_Library/Learn_the_API/VersionOne_REST_API_Tutorial

Comment: Thank you both very much. I'm sorry, this is just my lack of C# experience, but after adding suggested code, I'm getting errors "A field initializer cannot reference the non-static field, method, or property" on the following:
'connector'
'services'
'memberId'
'query' and 'result'

Comment: Latest code: I added suggested code after my .Build(); line....IServices services = new Services(connector);
    Oid memberId = services.GetOid("Member:20");
    Query query = new Query(memberId);
    QueryResult result = services.Retrieve(query);
    Asset member = result.Assets[0];

Comment: @DataCarniv0r  You're not going to be able to just copy and paste the code that we suggested.  You will need to change it to fit your needs.  Read the docs and get a good understanding of their API.

The code that was posted in my answer is just an example and is not guaranteed to work.